# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer Lifetime: Singleton

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

> Failed to compare two elements in the array.
> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl': Failed to compare two elements in the array.
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl': Failed to compare two elements in the array.)'

I'm working on a dot net core project where I got these exceptions.
the code is

```
services.AddEthereumWallet();

services.AddRippleRegistration();

services.AddALTCoinRegisteration();

services.AddWHCRegisteration();

services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services.AddScoped<IGroupRepository, GroupRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IGroupUserRepository, GroupUserRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IMeetingRespository, MeetingRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IMeetingUserRespository, MeetingUserRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();

services.AddScoped<ITranslationRepository, TranslationRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IUserActivityRepository, UserActivityRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IUserInfoRepository, UserInfoRepository>();

services.AddScoped<ICallRepository, CallRepository>();

services.AddScoped<ILoginRepository, LoginRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IChatRepository, ChatRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IWalletRepository, WalletRepository>();

services.AddScoped<IGroupChatRepository, GroupChatRepository>();

services.AddControllers();
```

I search a lot but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Could you please share your `ConfigureServices` details in addition, need to have a look on `DapperContext` and `HttpContextAccessor` details. Did you tried to replace with `services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); or 
    services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`. Please share the update with us.

Answer (score 2):

Update your NuGet package according to your Framework. You are using Bittrex library and Ethereum Node in your Project Some Nuget Packages are Conflicting with your Solution Project.

Comment: Did you get any revelation from god that you got to know he is using `Bittrex library` and `Ethereum Node` ? Even though he is using this how you got to know from the error and question he posted? Are you together spamming it?

Comment: services.AddEthereumWallet();
services.AddRippleRegistration();
services.AddALTCoinRegisteration();
Read question Carefully !